# Custom Tool Warning error verifying some XML Schemas during export

Tags: c#, php, soap, types, wsdl

I have a web service that I want to consume driven by PHP and SOAP. I can add the web service just fine and I get the list of methods when I added(used add service reference when added). But now I get an error:

> Warning    1   Custom tool warning: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during export:
>   Type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:struct' is not declared. localPATH:Reference.svcmap  1   1   SOAP_Webservice_Test

From what I understand, this is due to a specific type that I have in my PHP Soap API. I have googled but none of the mentioned fixes does it for me.

Any suggestions how to proceed with my debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this because the problem was not in the client, it was in the soap server I tried to refer to.